# How to solve for matrix $A$?

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

> Two matrices $A$ and $B$ satisfy the equation $$AB=I+2A$$ where $I$ is the identity matrix and $$B=\begin{bmatrix}3&-2\\-4&8\end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Find $A$

I’m stuck on this Matrices question. I’ve tried multiplying both sides by the inverse to get rid of B, but I don’t know what to do next.

Comment: Hint: Write $2A=2IA$ and then factor $A$.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Treat it as an equation
$$AB=I+2A\iff AB-2A=I\iff A(B-2I)=I\iff A=(B-2I)^{-1}$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn’t thought of that

Comment: You are welcome.